# Can I disable ssl for AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

"By default, the AWS CLI uses SSL when communicating with AWS services."
[base on the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)

Is there a way to let AWS CLI use HTTP? I tried to read the reference but didn't find it.

Comment: Not all endpoints support HTTP (see list at docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html). Did you try using `--endpoint-url http://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` (or whichever supported HTTP endpoint you need)?

Comment: What you mean by disable SSL? Disable certificate validation or use HTTP protocol?

Comment: What is your use case for doing this? You’d be sending API commands and credentials plain-text across the wire.

Comment: @Azize use HTTP. changed the question body.

Comment: @hephalump we have service running with HTTP protocal, I was trying to use CLI to simulate its behavior to do some investigation

Comment: Using HTTP is very dangerous as everything is sent over the Internet in the clear. If you must use an HTTP endpoint, do your CLI API discovery using an AWS EC2 instance. Create new AWS credential keys and then delete them after each testing session. This won't guarantee security, but will minimize the hops that can observe your traffic to just AWS networks.

Comment: @jamod remove -s from endpoint string is working. do you mind answer the question? thx.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly set endpoint to use http will do the work.
e.g. "http://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"

Thanks @jarmod.